# WCF SessionMode.Required and PerCall

Tags: wcf

When I set SessionMode = SessionMode.Required and InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall then session is present and every time I call method then new instance is created but is new session created as well? Based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) the answear is yes

> Behavior with sessionful channel: A session and InstanceContext for each call.

I created simple app and set

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IRepairCallbackContract), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```

and I was displaying

```
        Debug.WriteLine(Counter + "" + OperationContext.Current.SessionId);
        Counter += 1;
```

It turned out that Counter always equals 1 (default) and session is always the same so it would mean that session is preserved in contradistinction what is said in msdn.

I got confused since I am reading **Programming WCF Services, 3rd Edition** and there is statement:

> If the service is configured for per-call instantiation, there can still be a transport session, but for every call WCF will create new context used just for that call.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the msdn article is just badly written. You *could* interpret the sentence as

> An InstanceContext for each call, and a session.

Or it could be plain wrong, or, correct at the original time of writing and copied verbatim to the newer versions of .net.

Whichever, I would say that you have conclusively proved the behavior to be a consistent session across calls, which I must say is a surprising result. It may actually be a defect, or expected behavior.

In a way it kind of makes sense that if the channel is sessionfull then some machinery in the WCF stack would recognise this despite the instance being renewed each call. I mean, what would be the point of a single call session?

It may also have something to do with the fact that you've defined a duplex channel. I would repeat the test without defining the callback contract to get confirmation of the result.

Comment: Both with CallbackContract and without it outcome is equivalent.